# Diplomatic Immunity quest won't start

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I have completed the 'Blades in the Dark' main quest but the later mission 'Diplomatic Immunity' won't start.

I'm playing on PC and I don't have any mods installed.

Is it because I had used console commands to finish that earlier mission since the bug didn't let me absorb the soul of that dragon?

Comment: You should look into the dragon soul issue.  If you are still unable to absorb souls, you have data file conflicts.  Google DLC load order and see if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't mind using console commands again:

> setstage MQ201 30

This will set you to the first "Talk to Delphine" stage of the quest.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the Delphine dialog never gave me the option to ask "What's next", the selection just never appears in the dialog tree to ask.

I had to use the console to type "mq106 200" to end the quest "A Blade in the Dark"

The in the console type "setstage MQ201 30" to start the next quest "Diplomatic Immunity".  Thanks for help Comic Sans.